# php get images properties "title"

Tags: php, image, metadata

how can I get an Image file title with php?
I am talking about the title shown near author and comments in the file properties.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing you can get it with exif_read_data :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: yeah I've came across this while searching google but didn't understand exactly how to utilize it.

Comment: @Jake Take a look at the user comments under the documentation, great explanations :)

Answer (score -1):

It's easy with jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQUERY-PATH"></script>
<script>
$('img').each(function(){
alert( $(this).attr('title') );
});
</script>
```

Edit: do you mean the filename or title within the HTML?

Comment: I meant the file title. can I extract the vars from jquery into a php script?